# mapping values are not allowed here in "<unicode string>"

Tags: yaml

I am using `yml` properties for spring boot app. I am getting error on `yml` as below:

```
onboarding: 
  api: 
    something: 
      attribute1: 
      attribute2:
    somethingElse: 
      atribute: 
    base-url: http://enpoint.elasticbeanstalk.com
      users: /users ## error here on colon symbol
        save-update: /users/save-update
```

My usage is as below:

```java
@Value("${onboarding.api.base-url.users}")
@Value("${onboarding.api.base-url.users.save-update}")
```

What am I doing wrong? Getting same error on any online parser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML, every key has *one* value. A scalar is a value. A nested mapping is also a value. Apparently, you try to give the key `base-url` *two* values, the first one being an URL (which is a scalar) and the second one being a mapping containing a key `users`. That won't work.

So YAML parses `http://enpoint.elasticbeanstalk.com` and sees „okay, this key contains a scalar value“ and then on the next line, you start a nested mapping. This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

This would be valid YAML:

```yaml
onboarding: 
  api: 
    something: 
      attribute1: 
      attribute2:
    somethingElse: 
      atribute: 
    base-url: http://enpoint.elasticbeanstalk.com
    users: /users
    save-update: /users/save-update
```

so would this:

```yaml
onboarding: 
  api: 
    something: 
      attribute1: 
      attribute2:
    somethingElse: 
      atribute: 
    base:
      url: http://enpoint.elasticbeanstalk.com
      users:
        path: /users
        save-update: /users/save-update
```

Comment: Thank you for help. So I access users path by `onboarding.api.base.url.users`? it's value would be `http://enpoint.elasticbeanstalk.com/users`?

Comment: No, you access the path by `onboarding.api.base.users.path` and its value will be `/users`. YAML does not include any magic to concatenate paths found along the content structure.